# K8s: Is it possible to share folder between main container and sidecar?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Trying to move my services to K8s. I am using helm for that and I want to describe my example with issue:

I need to move few services with own Apache`s. Yes, I understand, that this is working something like:

external traffic -> K8s nginx ingress -> pod Apache

But I cant change it for now. Apache is working with PHP. So, I have deployment for two images: `php-fpm` and `Apache`. And, in this case, I need to share php files from my first php-fpm container with Apache.

For now - I am using shared `volumeMounts` to copying files from one container to second (all date is preparing/compiling in the first container, php-fpm, during the build):

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-files
    mountPath: /var/shared-www
```

And

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cp -r XXX /var/shared-www/"]
```

And it is working, but I would like to find solution to have one common point, like a symlink, to store files. I want to have ability to change files in one place and have changed files in both containers.

Is it possible?

PS I am using AWS EKS. And I don`t want to use network storage (like a EFS).

Comment: I might avoid trying to share files entirely in a container environment.  Can you build an image `FROM httpd`, `COPY` your static assets into that image, and run that as a separate Deployment?  Can you use a different application framework that's capable of serving its own static assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) as per official documentation:

> it is useful to share one volume for multiple uses in a single pod.
> The volumeMounts.subPath property specifies a sub-path inside the
> referenced volume instead of its root.

So instead of running the command something like (to share XXX towards):

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-files
    mountPath: /var/shared-www
    subpath: XXX
```

Update:

Kubernetes subpath vulnerability [article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/04/fixing-subpath-volume-vulnerability/)

Comment: Looking good, going to try it, thank you. Also, it is interesting - why it is not recomended for production (`...This sample subPath configuration is not recommended for production use....`)?

Comment: Check the answer update hope it helps

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/